# Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe using provider and snackbar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm using DismissibleWidget to remove a note from a list. When the note is removed a Snackbar is called to give the chance for the user to undo the action. When the button is clicked, and the note is reinserted  in the list, this error appears:

**The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.**

1. The dismissible widget

   ```
                Dismissible(
                   direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                   onDismissed: (direction){
                     var removedNote = list.notes[index];
                     Provider.of<ListProvider>(context, listen: false).removeNote(index);

                     Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                         SnackBar(
                           content: Text("Nota removida"),
                           action: SnackBarAction(
                             label: "Desfazer",
                             onPressed: (){
                               Provider.of<ListProvider>(context, listen: false).insertNote(removedNote, index);
                             },
                           ),
                           duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                         ),
                     );
                   },
   ```

   ...
2. The method in the provider

   ```
   void insertNote(NoteModel note, int index){
      notes.insert(index, note);
      fileRepository.saveToFile(notes);
      notifyListeners();
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

I faced the some problem but with BLoC as sate management, my solution was taking the context from above that widget.

#### What went wrong?

You were trying to look for a context that is no longer available. This ocurrs also because of [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

#### Solution?

Reach the content above that that widget.

Pseudo Flutter Code

```
class NameOfYourClass{
    build(BuildContext context1) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context2, index) {
             return MyItem(); 
          }
      );
    }
   }
```

Let's say you dismiss the `MyItem` with the `Dismissible` widget, the `context2` will be no longer available, if you print the `context2` it will look something like this(**NOTE**: When `MyItem` is Dismissed):

```
SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate#66afb(estimated child count: 1), renderObject: RenderSliverList#593ed relayoutBoundary=up2 DETACHED)
```

As you can see, the item is `DETACHED` from the tree. If you print the context1 it will look something like this.

```
NameOfYourClass
```

So in conclusion, instead of doing this:

```
 Provider.of<ListProvider>(context2, listen: false).insertNote(removedNote, index);
```

Do this:

```
 Provider.of<ListProvider>(context1, listen: false).insertNote(removedNote, index);
```

Don't use context1 or context2, this is for illustration purposes.

Comment: If you don't quite understand yet, let me know to make a reproducible sample code with Provider.